# O "artisan serve" precisa que o cmd continue aberto?

Tags: php, laravel

Ao digitar o comando `php artisan server` na pasta do do projeto laravel pelo `cmd` ele me retorna a mensagem:

```
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Percebo que a pagina web do larevel abre normalmente, mas o prompt fica travado "Startando.." é normal? Preciso ficar com esse prompt aberto sempre para rodar o servidor?

Comment: Sim, é normal amigo

Comment: ok, muito obrigado

Comment: Não necessariamente. Você pode rodar o comando `php artisan serve & exit` (no Linux). Ele vai fechar o terminal e continuar rodando o servidor.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, mas poderia ter sido "programada" de diferentes formas, mas ali o objetivo é simplesmente ter na tela saídas de log e possíveis erros já na própria interface.

Exemplo, eu baixei um projeto já iniciado em Laravel via git e tentei executar, mas o meu PHP local esta com algumas extensões necessárias desativadas, dessa forma eu posso obter o erro:

[image: exemplo de erro ao iniciar um projeto Laravel]

Você também poderia por conta própria "direcionar" o output para outro lugar ou forçar o processo iniciar em background no Windows executando:

```
start /B php artisan serve
```

Teria um resultado como esse:

```
C:\Users\new_g\laravel8>start /B php artisan serve

C:\Users\new_g\laravel8>Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Sun Jan  3 17:12:01 2021] PHP 8.0.0 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started

C:\Users\new_g\laravel8>
```

Claro que um programa de servidor local poderia fazer isso "naturalmente", mas isso depende de quem desenvolveu o programa e da intenção, não tem porque fazer coisas a mais em um programa simples que simplesmente funciona por linha de comando, ou seja com um simples <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> você pode matar o processo, finalizando assim o programa.

No final tudo depende de como as coisas são programadas, poderia alguém fazer algo como para iniciar:

```
c:\projetoX>server start --port 8000
c:\projetoX>server start --port 5000
```

Dessa forma iniciaria dois servidores com portas diferentes

E depois algo como:

```
c:\projetoX>server stop --port 8000
```

Dessa exibiria os logs só do servidor na porta 5000:

```
c:\projetoX>server log --port 5000
```

E apesar de não "travar o CMD/terminal" ainda sim por baixo existiria um processo rodando que o vinculo de facilitar o acesso dos logs ou finalizar seria a porta que você apontar, isso tudo depende de como os desenvolvedores vão criar o funcionamento. Apesar de no final não trazer grandes vantagens.